# Search for cached data only when a particular method invokes

Tags: java, spring, caching, spring-boot, ehcache

I would like to know if its possible to get the cached data only when invoked from a specific method, eg I have a method annotated as @Cacheable, I wanted it to just return what is cached when a particular method calls it, otherwise, Perform the method normally.

Answer (score 0):

Use Spring cache abstraction. 
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html

```
@Cacheable({"users"})
public User getUser(String userId) {
// Logic goes here
}
```

With this any Spring caches the returned objects returned from method with method input as keys. So this method is called the User is returned from Cache if found or else actual method is called an response is cached and returned.

This can be backed by any third party caches like redis, ehcache, hazelcast.

Comment: I am sorry, can you please explain how this answer's the question asked. The code snippet you have indicated will return the cached object when called from any method(with same arguments). But the question was something different. When a cached method(with @Cacheable) is called from a specifc method, only then cached entries need to be returned or else it should follow regular code flow whch is inside the method. Sorry If I am missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it using condition parameter of `@Cacheable` Annotation. Check here http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.0.RC1/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html section 28.3.1.3